# Logic Error: startWord substring

Tags: java, substring

My task is to use substring to pull out the first few letters of a string if it matches another given string. Basically, given a string and a second "word" string, we'll say that the word matches the string if it appears at the front of the string, except its first char does not need to match exactly. On a match, return the front of the string, or otherwise return the empty string. So with the string "hippo" the word "hi" returns "hi" and "xip" returns "hip". The word will be at least length 1.

The problem with my method is when **str** is just one letter and **word** is something else that doesn't match **str**, I run into a

> StringOutOfBound Exception

For example, if **str** is "h" and **word** is "ix", it should return nothing. Instead, my method crashes with the stringoutofbound exception. What can I do to fix my logic.

```
public String startWord(String str, String word) {
   int length;

   length = word.length();

    if (str.substring(0, length).equals(word))
      return str.substring(0, length);
   else if (str.substring(1, length).equals(word.substring(1, word.length())))
      return str.substring(0, length);
   else
      return "";   

}
```

Comment: What if str is `hiAll` and word is `hiEveryBody` what should be the result?

Comment: @TAsk idk. None of my required test cases had **word** vary drastically from **str**. To answer your question, I think the expected result would be "hi" because everything afterwards is different, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `str` length is smaller than `word` length. Please put a check before your logic: `if(str.length()<=word.length())`.

In the `else` part, always return `""`, as it will never satisfy your condition.

```
if(str.length()>=word.length())
{
   if (str.substring(0, length).equals(word))
      return str.substring(0, length);
   else if (str.substring(1, length).equals(word.substring(1, word.length())))
      return str.substring(0, length);
   else
      return ""; 
}
else{
    return "";  
}
```

Comment: How would I apply a check using: `if (str.length()<=word.length())`

Without affecting the rest of my code?

Comment: @AwkardGuy Edited the answer to include the code. Please mark it correct if it answers your question.

Comment: Everything worked fine after I changed the less than to greater than. Other than that, thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

Correct your conditions this way:

```
if (str.substring(0, Math.min(length, str.length())).equals(word))
    return str.substring(0, length);
else if (str.substring(1, Math.min(length, str.length())).equals(word.substring(1, word.length()))) {
    return str.substring(0, length);
}
else
    return "";
```

Comment: It did a great job in solving one of my exceptions, but I ran into another problem when str is empty and word is composed of one letter. The result should be nothing.